# AJAX asynchronous causing null value.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a form with select option which displays some options, I want to retrieve the selected option to display it in a text box. I am using AJAX to retrieve some xml data to display as options.

After displaying the options, and when i try to retrieve the selected option I get `null` in asynchronous AJAX, but in synchronous AJAX call I get the right value.

Here is my code:

```
function loadXML(url, callback){
    $.ajax ({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: callback,
    });
}

function displaySubjects(){
    loadXML("subjects.xml", function(xml){
        $(xml).find("subject").each(function(){
            var courseCode = $(this).find("code")[0].textContent;
            var courseTitle = $(this).find("title")[0].textContent;
            $('#subject').append("<option value='" + courseCode + "'>" + courseCode + ": " +courseTitle + "</option>");
        })
    });
}

displaySubjects();
console.log($("#subject").val()); //Returns 'null'.
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: You do know what "asynchronous" means, right? You "fix" it by doing your processing in the callback.

Comment: @nnnnnn thats what i have done, I'm using an anonymous function as a callback. Is this correct?

Comment: You are reading the value outside of the callback! It is like eating a pizza before the delivery man brings it to your house. Place the console.log in your callback.

Comment: You are supposed to do processing in your callback in asynchronous requests. Put your console.log in callback function.

Comment: I don't understand why the Ajax code that adds options is related to you getting the selected option? When you add the options in your function you don't set any of them to selected...

Comment: You guys dont understand my question. I know what asynchronous means. I need to retrieve the selected option from outside the callback function. Iam just printing it to the console just to test it, but i need to use the value somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling console.log() before ajax callback complete. One thing you can do is add another function and call it inside the success callback.

```
function loadXML(url, callback){
    $.ajax ({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: callback,
    });
}

function displaySubjects(){
    loadXML("subjects.xml", function(xml){
        $(xml).find("subject").each(function(){
            var courseCode = $(this).find("code")[0].textContent;
            var courseTitle = $(this).find("title")[0].textContent;
            $('#subject').append("<option value='" + courseCode + "'>" + courseCode + ": " +courseTitle + "</option>");
        });
        callMeAfterRequestComplete();
    });


}

function callMeAfterRequestComplete(){
  console.log($("#subject").val());
}

displaySubjects();
```

Comment: ok, thnx, i needed to retrieve the value for the select option outside the callback function.